# What is the Eclipse shortcut for Open Declaration?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't like using the mouse and this is one of the few times I have to use it so maybe if someone knows the shortcut for when you show the declaration of the method by clicking the mouse while you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, that would be very helpful :)

Comment: Not sure, so posting as a comment... does F3 do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When your cursor is on the method press <kbd>F3</kbd>, eclipse will take you to the declaration .  
By default it's bound to <kbd>F3</kbd>, but you can rebind it to a different key, go to Windows >> Preferences >> Keys, and change the Open Declaration binding...

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify that for sure. F3 is too uncomfortable.